# Python code works on linux, error occurs on windows(backslashes)

Tags: python, windows, tesseract

So I have a personal project which I know is pretty inefficient but works. I am writing a python code that executes the non pip version of tesseract(apt installed in linux). My code works on linux, but I get this error on windows:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
> specified: 'DRIVE_LETTER:\PROJECT_FOLDER\FOLDER/FILE.txt'

I am using the Atom IDE, pretty new to python so if anyone can point out my idiotic mistakes I would appreciate it, thanks! The error occurs on the *subprocess.run* line because the error.txt file says it cannot find the specific path.

**This is my code:**

```
from flask import Flask,url_for,redirect,render_template,request,send_file
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import subprocess

app=Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_DIRECTORY']="uploads/"
app.config['FILE_NAME']=""
app.config['OUTPUT_DIRECTORY']="textresult/"
app.config['EXTENSION']=".txt"

@app.route("/",methods=["POST","GET"])
def to_upload():
    err_msg=""
    if request.method=="POST":
        if request.files['fileupload']:
            f=request.files['fileupload']
            filename=secure_filename(f.filename)
            app.config['FILE_NAME']=filename
            f.save(app.config['UPLOAD_DIRECTORY']+filename)
            return redirect(url_for("process_upload",filename=filename))
        else:
            err_msg="No file selected!"
    return render_template("index.html",error=err_msg)

@app.route("/upload/<filename>",methods=["POST","GET"])
def process_upload(filename):
    f1=open("logs/out.txt","w")
    f2=open("logs/error.txt","w")
    out=subprocess.run([f"tesseract uploads/{filename}"+f" textresult/{filename}"],shell=True,stdout=f1,stderr=f2)
    return redirect(url_for("output_file"))

@app.route("/result/",methods=["GET"])
def output_file():
    return render_template("output.html")

@app.route("/download/")
def download_file():
    file=app.config['OUTPUT_DIRECTORY']+app.config['FILE_NAME']+app.config['EXTENSION']
    return send_file(file,as_attachment=True)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0",port="2000",debug=True)
```

EDIT:
Finally got it to work! Removed / in app.config['UPLOAD_DIRECTORY'] and app.config['OUTPUT_DIRECTORY'] since now I am using os.path.join and these are the following lines for both Linux and Windows that I got them to work at:

**Linux:**

```
to_convert=os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_DIRECTORY'],filename)
convert2txt=os.path.join(app.config['OUTPUT_DIRECTORY'],filename)
out=subprocess.run(["tesseract %s %s"%(to_convert,convert2txt)],shell=True,stdout=f1,stderr=f2)
```

**Windows:**

```
to_convert=os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_DIRECTORY'],filename)
convert2txt=os.path.join(app.config['OUTPUT_DIRECTORY'],filename)
out=subprocess.run(["tesseract",to_convert,convert2txt],shell=True,stdout=f1,stderr=f2)
```

Thank you all for your inputs!

Comment: Use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to manipulate paths instead of butchering them manually

Comment: This question should be asked on StackOverflow rather than here; it is a general programming question and has nothing to do with Ubuntu in particular.

Comment: to me this is a windows problem :P "Python code works on linux, error occurs on windows(backslashes)"

Comment: Thank you all of you, I am not frequent here but since I am learning python I thought I should drop by this account again after a few years. But I could've sworn I posted this on stalkoverflow, sorry I am quite new here technically so I wasn't aware of the rules. But thank you so much for the outputs!

Edit: Now I get it, on the top right corner I clicked on askubuntu instead of stackoverflow, my bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question does not belong here; it should be asked on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) site as this is a general programming question and is in no way Ubuntu-specific.

But the answer to your question is rather simple: you are manually creating paths to files in your code by using `/` as the filename separator, like here:

```
    f1=open("logs/out.txt","w")
    f2=open("logs/error.txt","w")
    out=subprocess.run([f"tesseract uploads/{filename}"+f" textresult/{filename}"],shell=True,stdout=f1,stderr=f2)
```

While this indeed works in Linux, it can't work in Windows, because the filename separator in Windows is `\` and not `/`. Windows does not recognize `/` as filename separator and likewise Linux does not recognize `\`.

If you want to have an OS-independent code, use `os.path.join()` to join the parts of the pathname, so instead for example `"logs/out.txt"` use `os.path.join("logs","out.txt")`. `os.path.join()` joins its arguments with a separator that is correct for the OS used.

Comment: I am sorry, will take note with the forum guidelines and thank you so much for your answer!